# SQLite tricky if join

Tags: sql, sqlite, if-statement, left-join

I have the following two tables:

T1 (id,name)
T2 (id,hybrid_col)

What I want to do is select all from T2 and JOIN with T1 if hybrid_col is numeric.
Basically, hybrid_col holds an id reference to T1 (in which case I want to get the name from T1) or a text string (in which case I just want hybrid_col).

How can I do that please?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you can join them? with T1.ID and T2.ID? or just with the hybrid col sometimes when T2.hybridcol is equals to T1.ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to just UNION the two cases:

```
SELECT id, hybrid_col
FROM T2
WHERE hybrid_col+0!=hybrid_col
UNION
SELECT T2.id,t1.name
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.hybrid_col=T1.id;
```

There is no need to check if hybrid_col is numeric if it has a match with T1.ID. If T1.ID is always numeric, non-numerics will be left out of the join.

EDIT: To sort them, encapsulate the result and sort that:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE
FROM
(
    SELECT id as "ID", hybrid_col as "Value"
    FROM T2
    WHERE hybrid_col+0!=hybrid_col
    UNION
    SELECT T2.id as "ID",t1.name as "Value"
    FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.hybrid_col=T1.id
) Q
ORDER BY ID;
```

There are other ways, like piping the result into a temp table and querying that, but the above is probably the simplest one-query approach.

Comment: That works, thank you MPelletier. Just two questions: Should I worry about speed using that? How do I order the result by a column in T1 and have them mix (I mean elements from both selects).

Comment: Speed will mostly depend on how much data there is total, and indexing on hybrid_col and T1.id. As for sorting, see my edit.

Comment: Uhm... what if there are two hybrid columns? I'd have to have 4 selects combined with union, right?

Comment: @Francisc Depending on how they are structured, yes, I think so. You know why most SQL database engines don't support hybrid column types? Because it's not meant to be that way. A well structured, relational  database should have columns that hold one item each only.

Comment: I'm against hybrid columns as well. It's probably best that I redo this part of the database now, when it's still in its infancy than later when it will be hugely complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely take the time to design that part, especially if you have the opportunity. If some T2 entries need the T1 entry, make that a dedicated field, or give all T2 entries a T1, or else put it all in T2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, this should be:

```
SELECT
(
  CASE 
     WHEN T2.HYBRID_COL = T1.ID THEN T1.NAME
      ELSE T2.HYBRID_COL
   END
) AS COLUMN
T2, T1
WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
and ISNUMERIC(T1.HYBRID_COL ) = 1
```

**Edit :** Don't know if you were looking for the ISNUMERIC because the T1.ID is numeric, if  it is that case just remove the  `and ISNUMERIC(T1.HYBRID_COL ) = 1` it should work anyway because the select validates that the `T2.HYBDRID_COL` matches with the `T1.ID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
select id,
(case when ISNUMERIC(hybrid_col) = 1 then name
else hybrid_col end) as custom_col
from
(select T2.id,T2.hybrid_col,T1.name from T2 left join T1 on T2.id = T1.id) mytab
```

Comment: Sadly, there is no `ISNUMERIC` function in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without using ISNUMERIC (which is unavailable in SQLite)

```
SELECT IFNULL(T1.name, T2.hybrid_col) AS [name]
FROM T2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 ON CAST(T1.id AS VARCHAR) = T2.hybrid_col
```

This should work for you, but due to the type cast you will likely lose any benefits from indexing that you might otherwise have on T1.id